# How to get rid of Invalid Mark error while reading a file in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file but I am getting **IOException: Invalid mark error** when I run the code even though it outputs the correct result just before the exception. If I increase the value of the mark (to around 40) it produces the complete and correct output but with NullPointerException.

Here's my code:

```
     private static void readEventsFile2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ArrayList<String> evtList = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("src/idse/Events.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String a ="";

        try {
            
            while(!(a=br.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
                
                if (isNum(a)){ 
                    numEv = Integer.parseInt(a);
                    System.out.println(numEv);
                } else if(!a.isEmpty()){ 
                    String[] parts = a.split(":");
                    for (String part : parts) {
                        evtList.add(part);
                    }
                }
                br.mark(0);
                a = br.readLine();
                if(a == null || isNum(a)) { 
                    System.out.println(evtList);
                    evtList.clear();
                }
                br.reset();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException | IllegalStateException | NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
    }
```

Output from the above code (line 149 is br.reset()):

```
5
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1, Pizza’s ordered online, 0.5]
10
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mark invalid
    at java.io.BufferedReader.reset(BufferedReader.java:512)
    at idse.IDSE.readEventsFile2(IDSE.java:149)
    at idse.IDSE.main(IDSE.java:188)
```

Format of the file I am reading:

```
5
Logins:2:Total time online:1:Emails sent:1:Orders processed:1:
Pizza’s ordered online:0.5:
10
Logins:7:Total time online:5:Emails sent:9:Orders processed:15:
Pizza’s ordered online:0.9:Logouts:6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The int parameter in `mark()` indicates the number of characters/bytes to be stored in the buffer. If you read too much data that crosses the size of the mark, then the `mark` will be `invalidated`. And upon calling `reset()`, it will give that exception.

If you read the document for `reset()`, it says it throws:

```
IOException - If the stream has never been marked,or if the mark has been invalidated
```

You can fix your code by increasing the capacity of the mark parameter.

```
br.mark(1000); // 1000 or depending on your buffer.
```

**Complete Code:**

```
private static void readEventsFile2() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    ArrayList<String> evtList = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Abi.Shaquib\\Desktop\\overflow.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String a = "";
    while ((a = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (isNum(a)) {
            int numEv = Integer.parseInt(a);
            System.out.println(numEv);
        } else if (!a.isEmpty()) {
            String[] parts = a.split(":");
            for (String part : parts) {
                evtList.add(part);
            }
        }
        br.mark(1000);
        a = br.readLine();
        if (a == null || isNum(a)) {
            System.out.println(evtList);
            evtList.clear();
        }
        br.reset();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
[Logins, 2, Total time online, 1, Emails sent, 1, Orders processed, 1, Pizza\'s ordered online, 0.5]
10
[Logins, 7, Total time online, 5, Emails sent, 9, Orders processed, 15, Pizza\'s ordered online, 0.9, Logouts, 6]
```

Comment: I increased the capacity of mark parameter but then I start getting NullPointerException

Comment: `while ((a = br.readLine()) != null) {` use this in your while loop. `isEmpty` doesn't  checks for `null`

Comment: What's the int value are you giving?How long is your input??

Comment: The format that I have pasted at the bottom is whats in the file. I have tried many values for mark from 0 to thousands. None of them work I either get Invalid mark or NullPointerException.

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the code you posted and its working now! I even tried with values greater than 1000 before but it didn't work that time.